# My JavaScript won't work before i resize my browser window, and almost all my CSS is working, except for a few lines (idk what's the problem here)

Tags: javascript, html, css

I am trying to make the second page of my Website, but some of the CSS and JS seem to not work.
I have 4 files, and 4 folders (all located in 1 same folder). The first folder is **view**, which contains *index.html* (the main page of the website), and *links.html* (the file that isn't working). Then there is the **js** folder which contains *script.js*. The third folder is **css** and inside of it is *style.css*. The final folder is **asset** which has image assets for my Website.

Here is the content of *index.html* :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Linkeld</title>
    <!-- CSS Links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <!-- JS Links -->
    <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="loader">
        <span>
            <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="topnav" class="transparent">
        <div class="wrapper main">
            <div class="wrapper left" id="navLogo">
                <img src="../asset/9984-confusion.png" alt="logo">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper right" id="navLinks">
                <a href="#" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="links.html">Links</a>
                <a href="account.html">Account</a>
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="head">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <img src="../asset/9984-confusion.png" alt="logo">
            <h1>Linkeld</h1>
            <h2>With over 1.000.000 links worldwide</h2>
            <div id="signup">
                <a href="" class="button">Sign-Up Now!</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="aboutWebsite">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="card">
                    <h1><i class="fas fa-share-alt"></i> Share</h1>
                    <p>Share links to people across the globe to discover, the limitation is only your imagination</p>
                    <div class="image" id="image1">
                        <img src="../asset/brooke-cagle-g1Kr4Ozfoac-unsplash-removebg-preview.png" alt="image1">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h1><i class="fas fa-search"></i> Discover</h1>
                    <p>Discover new websites from other people via links, you can visit all of the internet's website!
                    </p>
                    <div class="image" id="image2">
                        <img src="../asset/grzegorz-walczak-yoIIPcrWhjI-unsplash-removebg-preview.png" alt="image2">
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h1><i class="fas fa-times-circle"></i> No Restrictions</h1>
                    <p>No restricted links or banned sites, share whatever you like</p>
                    <div class="image" id="image3">
                        <img src="../asset/cdd20-vR6bNYTVlpo-unsplash-removebg-preview.png" alt="image3">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="whySignup">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="section">
                    <h1><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> Why Sign-Up?</h1>
                    <p>Firstly, you'll be able to share links with others! Not just click them.</p>
                    <p>Secondly, you can like and save links to your account, so you can view at them later.</p>
                    <p>Thirdly, you'll be able to customize your Username! No more plain old nicknames.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <img src="../asset/sincerely-media-4dSXcNTyXaI-unsplash.jpg" alt="image4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="phishing">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="section">
                    <h1><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> Would i fall to phishing?</h1>
                    <p>Well technically, yes, you will at some point fall into a phishing scam.</p>
                    <p>But, you can check the domain first, before clicking the link.</p>
                    <p>Check for any typos, or weird characters. A site that has a suspicious looking domain may be a
                        phishing website so be careful.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <img src="../asset/sincerely-media-4dSXcNTyXaI-unsplash.jpg" alt="image4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="nfsw">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="section">
                    <h1><i class="fas fa-question-circle"></i> Can I post NFSW related stuff?</h1>
                    <p>There is no limitation to what website you want to share here.</p>
                    <p>So yes you absolutely can post NFSW related content here and not get banned.</p>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <img src="../asset/sincerely-media-4dSXcNTyXaI-unsplash.jpg" alt="image4">
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="signupCall">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="section">
                    <h1>What are you waiting for?</h1>
                </div>
                <div class="section">
                    <div>
                        <a class="button" href="">Sign-Up Now!</a>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="foot">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="section">
                <h2>Other resources</h2>
                <a href="">Home</a>
                <a href="">Copyright</a>
                <a href="">Terms</a>
                <a href="">Policy</a>
                <a href="">Sources</a>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <h2>About us</h2>
                <a href="">Team</a>
                <a href="">About</a>
                <a href="">Site Stats</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

And here is *links.html* :

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Linkeld</title>
    <!-- CSS Links -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../css/style.css">
    <!-- JS Links -->
    <script src="../js/script.js"></script>
    <!-- Font Awesome -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/font-awesome/5.15.3/css/all.min.css">
</head>

<body>
    <div id="loader">
        <span>
            <i class="fas fa-spinner fa-spin"></i>
        </span>
    </div>
    <div id="topnav" class="transparent">
        <div class="wrapper main">
            <div class="wrapper left" id="navLogo">
                <img src="../asset/9984-confusion.png" alt="logo">
            </div>
            <div class="wrapper right" id="navLinks">
                <a href="index.html" class="active">Home</a>
                <a href="#">Links</a>
                <a href="account.html">Account</a>
                <a href="about.html">About</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="head">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <img src="../asset/9984-confusion.png" alt="logo">
            <h1>Links</h1>
            <h2 style="margin-bottom: 100px;">This is where you'll find links to Websites!</h2>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="main">
        <div id="linksList">
            <div class="wrapper">
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="card">
                    <h3>By [user]</h3>
                    <a href="[user-input-link]">[user input]</a>
                    <div class="description">
                        <p>[user input]</p>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
    <div id="foot">
        <div class="wrapper">
            <div class="section">
                <h2>Other resources</h2>
                <a href="">Home</a>
                <a href="">Copyright</a>
                <a href="">Terms</a>
                <a href="">Policy</a>
                <a href="">Sources</a>
            </div>
            <div class="section">
                <h2>About us</h2>
                <a href="">Team</a>
                <a href="">About</a>
                <a href="">Site Stats</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Now for the CSS (*style.css*) :

```css
@import url('https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Roboto:ital,wght@0,100;0,300;0,400;0,500;0,700;0,900;1,100;1,300;1,400;1,500;1,700;1,900&display=swap');

* {
    box-sizing: border-box;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
    font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
}

:root {
    /* CSS HEX */
    --lime-green: #1ec90eff;
    --metallic-sunburst: #9b7e46ff;
    --mellow-apricot: #f4b266ff;
    --dark-liver-horses: #544343ff;
}

html {
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

a {
    color: var(--lime-green);
    text-decoration: none;
    transition: text-decoration 0.3s ease-in-out;
}

a:hover {
    text-decoration: underline;
}

a:visited {
    color: var(--lime-green);
}

#topnav {
    position: fixed;
    width: 100%;
    z-index: 99;
    background: white;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 6px 12px -2px,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 3px 7px -3px;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#topnav.transparent {
    background: transparent;
    box-shadow: none;
}

#topnav .wrapper.main {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: stretch;
}

#topnav .wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

#topnav .wrapper#navLogo {
    width: 70%;
}

#topnav .wrapper#navLogo img {
    padding: 10px;
    width: 60px;
    margin-left: 40px;
}

#topnav .wrapper#navLinks {
    flex: 1;
    justify-content: space-evenly;
}

#topnav.transparent .wrapper#navLinks a {
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: white;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#topnav .wrapper#navLinks a {
    color: black;
    padding: 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align: center;
    transition: all 0.2s ease-in-out;
}

#head {
    background: url("../asset/sincerely-media-4dSXcNTyXaI-unsplash.jpg");
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#head .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
}

#head .wrapper h1,
#head .wrapper h2 {
    color: white;
}

#head .wrapper img {
    width: 40px;
    margin: 100px 0 20px 0;
}

#head .wrapper h1 {
    font-size: 90px;
}

#head .wrapper h2 {
    font-size: 18px;
}

#head #signup {
    margin: 80px 0 100px 0;
}

#head #signup a {
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    background: var(--mellow-apricot);
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    display: block;
}

#head #signup a:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

#aboutWebsite .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: center;
}

#aboutWebsite .wrapper .card {
    width: 400px;
    margin: 20px;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 6px 12px -2px,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 3px 7px -3px;
    padding: 80px 60px;
}

#aboutWebsite .wrapper .card h1 {
    font-size: 40px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    font-weight: 300;
}

#aboutWebsite .wrapper .card p {
    font-size: 18px;
}

#aboutWebsite .wrapper .card .image {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
}

#aboutWebsite .wrapper .card .image img {
    width: 300px;
}

#aboutWebsite .wrapper .card .image#image1,
#aboutWebsite .wrapper .card .image#image2 {
    margin-top: 130px;
}

#foot {
    margin-top: 50px;
    background: rgb(235, 235, 235);
}

#foot .wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

#foot .wrapper .section {
    flex: 1;
    padding: 50px 30px;
}

#foot .wrapper .section a {
    display: block;
    color: black;
    margin-bottom: 30px;
    width: max-content;
}

#foot .wrapper .section h2 {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
}

#loader {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    background: white;
    z-index: 999;
}

#loader.loaded {
    display: none;
}

#loader span {
    font-size: 100px;
}

a.button {
    color: white;
    padding: 20px;
    background: var(--mellow-apricot);
    border-radius: 10px;
    transition: all 0.3s ease-in-out;
    display: block;
}

a.button:hover {
    text-decoration: none;
    transform: scale(1.1);
}

#whySignup {
    width: 65%;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 6px 12px -2px,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 3px 7px -3px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#whySignup .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#whySignup .wrapper .section:first-child {
    padding: 50px 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

#whySignup .wrapper .section:first-child h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#whySignup .wrapper .section:first-child p {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#whySignup .wrapper .section img {
    width: 450px;
    height: 500px;
}

#phishing {
    width: 65%;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 6px 12px -2px,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 3px 7px -3px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#phishing .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    flex-direction: row-reverse;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#phishing .wrapper .section:first-child {
    padding: 50px 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

#phishing .wrapper .section:first-child h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#phishing .wrapper .section:first-child p {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#phishing .wrapper .section img {
    width: 450px;
    height: 500px;
}

#nfsw {
    width: 65%;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 6px 12px -2px,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 3px 7px -3px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#nfsw .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    justify-content: start;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#nfsw .wrapper .section:first-child {
    padding: 50px 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
}

#nfsw .wrapper .section:first-child h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
}

#nfsw .wrapper .section:first-child p {
    font-size: 18px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#nfsw .wrapper .section img {
    width: 450px;
    height: 500px;
}

#signupCall {
    width: 65%;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 6px 12px -2px,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 3px 7px -3px;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-radius: 20px;
}

#signupCall .wrapper {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    transition: all 0.5s ease-in-out;
}

#signupCall .wrapper .section:first-child {
    padding: 50px 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    background: transparent;
}

#signupCall .wrapper .section:first-child h1 {
    font-weight: 300;
    margin-bottom: 40px;
    font-size: 50px;
}

#signupCall .wrapper .section:first-child h2 {
    font-size: 20px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
}

#signupCall .wrapper .section {
    background: url("../asset/sincerely-media-4dSXcNTyXaI-unsplash.jpg");
    background-position: -45%;
    padding: 50px 20px;
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    flex-direction: column;
    justify-content: center;
    height: 300px;
}

#linksList {
    padding: 50px;
}

#linksList .wrapper {
    display: flex;
}

#linksList .wrapper .cards {
    padding: 30px;
    box-shadow: rgba(50, 50, 93, 0.25) 0px 6px 12px -2px,
        rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.3) 0px 3px 7px -3px;
    width: 120px;
    margin: 30px;
    background: cyan;
}
```

Here's *script.js* :

```js
window.addEventListener("load", () => {
    const loader = document.getElementById("loader");
    loader.classList.add("loaded");
})

window.addEventListener("scroll", () => {
    let scrollY = window.scrollY;
    let posY = 450;
    let topnav = document.getElementById("topnav");
    if (scrollY < posY) {
        topnav.classList.add("transparent");
    } else {
        topnav.classList.remove("transparent");
    }
});
```

Now the problem is that **#linksList** doesn't seem to change even though I've written the CSS in *style.css*. What's wrong about it? I can't seem to find anything that could've conflicted with the CSS. I even gave the **.card** in **#linksList** a cyan background to test if it works, but to no result.

Then there's the **#topnav**, the JS won't add the class **.transparent** when the user scrolled to the **#topnav** in *links.html* until the browser's screen was resized (I'm using Chrome). I have no actual clue about what is going on here. Maybe it's just my browser acting weird or is it because I made some kind of mistake in the scripting?

(sorry for the long question)